# How to link libraries without root permissions

Tags: debian, libraries, linker

I am trying to compile OpenMPI without root permissions on my local account in a cluster, but I have the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libcm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnuma
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libverbs
```

Is there a way to link theses libraries without administrative permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need special permissions to use libraries in compile/build/link time; they must however be installed or present in the system.

Or in alternative, you can even compile them yourself and link them from your home directory if the development tools are installed.

To install the libraries in a ubuntu system:

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev libibverbs-dev
```

I have not been able to find the corresponding libcm package.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libcm
```

you should install `libibcm-devel` to get `libibcm.so`.
It contains both libraries `/usr/lib64/libibcm.a` amd `/usr/lib64/libibcm.so`.